Multiple targets of the same name in Makefile
In our project, the Makefile contains the following lines:
# C Files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    +$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -D__FILENAME__='"$(<F)"' $(CWARNS) -c $< -o $@

# C++ Files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    +$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -D__FILENAME__='"$(<F)"' $(CPPWARNS) -c $< -o $@

I can see in the output that Objectfiles for .c files are treated by the first target, .cpp files by the second.
However, I am quite confused that this works. In both cases, the targetname is $(OBJDIR)/%.o, how does make decide which target to use?

As long as the basename of the source files are different (e.g. you don't have both foo.c and foo.cpp) the target will be different. That's how the wildcard replacement % works.

"The target" is ambiguous in your comment.  The object file will certainly not be different: you can create foo.o from foo.c., foo.cpp, foo.F, etc. etc.

The pattern rule is chosen by the algorithm described in the manual:

It is possible that more than one pattern rule will meet these criteria. In that case, make will choose the rule with the shortest stem (that is, the pattern that matches most specifically). If more than one pattern rule has the shortest stem, make will choose the first one found in the makefile.

Basically, all the patterns that could match (that have prerequisites that could be built) are discovered, then the one with the shortest stem is used.  This actually depends somewhat on what version of GNU Make you are using: older versions didn't consider "shortest stem" and always used the first pattern rule that was eligible.

For your example, as others have noted, it's unlikely you'll have both a foo.c and foo.cpp (for example) in the same makefile.  If you do, and you want to build both, you'll have to use different targets.  For example some makefiles use foo.cpp.o and foo.c.o instead.

So, if I understand correctly, the pattern matching will try to find an existing prerequisite, and only then %.o will be matched.
Before, I thought that the makefile is searched for a matching pattern, similar to a ls *.o, which gives me all .o files.

Neither of the above is quite correct.  Make always works from the goal, backwards.  The goal is either the target(s) you specify on the command line, or if you don't then the first target in the makefile (subject to some special cases).

To try to build a target, make first tries to build all its prerequisites.  Then if the target is out of date, it runs the target's recipe.  So, if you have all: foo; foo: foo.o then the goal is all, then make tries to build foo, then it tries to build foo.o.  Since there's no explicit rule, make searches the pattern rules, looking for ones that match foo.o.  When it finds one, it tries to build each of the pattern rule prerequisites.  If they can't be built, the rule doesn't match and make looks for more rules.  If multiple match it uses the algorithm in the manual to choose.

Often this is a non-issue because only one of the inputs would be available.
In the rare case that you have both a foo.c and foo.cpp, the GNU Make manual has the following to say:

Of course, when you write the makefile, you know which implicit rule you want make to use, and you know it will choose that one because you know which possible prerequisite files are supposed to exist.

When testing this in practice, it just picks the first-defined implicit rule in the database that matches.
For explicit targets this ambiguity is not tolerated:

There can only be one recipe to be executed for a file. If more than one rule gives a recipe for the same file, make uses the last one given and prints an error message.


This is not correct.  The quoted part of the manual is for explicit rules.  The question is related to implicit (pattern) rules.

Thanks for that correction. I could not find any information about overlapping implicits beyond the smug "Of course, when you write the makefile, you know which implicit rule you want make to use, and you know it will choose that one because you know which possible prerequisite files are supposed to exist."
